# reloadData method not called from another class

Tags: iphone

I will directly start from an ex:
I have two classes A and B, both are derived from UITableViewController.

I have also added them into navigation controller so there is navigation going on from A to B. These both classes use database for showing data into the table. Now in B View I delete a row from the DB and A view displays the row count of that DB table. Now what I am doing is on the BACK button of the navigation I want to I am calling this method 
TRY 1:

```
//in class B
-(IBAction)backBtnPressed
{
[ObjA.tbleView reloadData];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnitmated:YES]; 
}
```

on its action. The problem is this method does not reload the data of View A. i.e., it doesn't call the tbleView's delegate methods like cellForIndexPath...etc.
Then I thought that may the reloadData shud be called from the same class so did this 
TRY 2:

```
//in class B
-(IBAction)backBtnPressed
{
[ObjA.tbleView myReloadData];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnitmated:YES]; 
}
//Class A
-(void)myReloadData
{
[self.tbleView reloadData];
}
```

It comes into this method but still doesn't call the tableView delegate methods. Please let me know why I am not able to do this silly thing :(.
Regards..
Amit

Answer (score 1):

Have you connected the `UITableView`'s `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets correctly (either in your nib or using code, depending on how you create the table)?

Comment: Yes I have connected the TableView control with the File's owner on the XIB file. Also connected thru code using these line of code :
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"My Worklist", @"WorkListViewController title");
self.tblObj.delegate = self;
self.tblObj.dataSource = self;
self.tblObj.rowHeight = 65;
self.tblObj.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
self.tblObj.sectionHeaderHeight = 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

You're close, put this in class A:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but already tried doing this but my viewWillAppear method is not called. I tried a lot but i don't know why this method is not called automatically :o(.